# Detecting which desktop gadgets are running on Windows 7 using C#

Tags: c#, .net, windows, process, windows-desktop-gadgets

I need to detect which Windows 7 Gadgets are currently loaded. I know for a fact that the process they run within is "explorer.exe" and that the each gadget has a window class is called `SideBar_HTMLHostWindow` with in instance of `Internet Explorer_Server` (snapshot attached).

However, I am not able to enumerate any further child windows or get window text etc. Any help would be appreciated.

[image: Snapshot]

**UPDATE:** This may be easier than it seems. Since it is tied to windows and remembers which gadgets are supposed to run at startup, there may be some data stored in the registry or disk perhaps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer: C:\Users\Raheel Khan\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows Sidebar\Settings.ini. This file gets updated every time a gadget is added or removed.